# How to clear cached query while i am using array driver in my laravel applications?

Tags: laravel

I have implemented query cached in my application and my cache driver
is `array`. But I want to clear all the cached query after certain time.

How can I do so using CLI or in controller ?

Answer (score 1):

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

and in controller:

```
Artisan::call('cache:clear');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this artisan commands for clearing cache from your laravel project:

```
//---Remove Routes Cache
php artisan route:clear;
php artisan route:cache
//---Flush the application cache
php artisan cache:clear;
//---Remove the configuration cache file
php artisan config:cache;
php artisan config:clear;
//---Clearing View Cache
php artisan view:clear;
php artisan view:cache;
```

To learn more about cache please visit the following URL:

[https://dev.to/kenfai/laravel-artisan-cache-commands-explained-41e1#:~:text=To%20clear%20your%20application%20cache,cache%3Aclear%20Application%20cache%20cleared](https://dev.to/kenfai/laravel-artisan-cache-commands-explained-41e1#:%7E:text=To%20clear%20your%20application%20cache,cache%3Aclear%20Application%20cache%20cleared)!

Answer (score 0):

```php
Artisan::call(['cache:clear']);
```

will run the command `php artisan cache:clear`. If you want it to be done automatically, you could call that command in the scheduler.

`app/Console/Kernel.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('cache:clear')->weekly();
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

This will run automatically if you add this entry to your crontab.

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

[More on running the scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/scheduling#running-the-scheduler)